# How can i bind in Xamarin to my Realmdatabase?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, realm

I am writing an app where I want to store the settings in a realm database.
For some reason the data binding, for my realm model, is not working. But when I define a property in the viewmodel and try to bind, everything works fine.

My Realm-Model:

```
       public class AppSettings : RealmObject
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public string Oid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public string MailAdress { get; set; }
        public string Pwd { get; set; }
        public string stdToAdress { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

My ViewModel:

```
      class SettingsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        private Realm _realm;

        public AppSettings AppSettings;
        public Command ChangeConfig { get; }

        public string test { get; set; }  //this works


        public SettingsViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Einstellungen";


            this._realm = DbSetup.GetMyInstance();
            this.AppSettings = this.GetSettings();

            this.ChangeConfig = new Command(OnConfigChanged);
            
        }

        private void OnConfigChanged()
        {

            Console.WriteLine($"Oid: {this.AppSettings.Oid}, Name: {this.AppSettings.Name}, mail: {this.AppSettings.MailAdress}, PersId: {this.AppSettings.PersonId}, PWD: {this.AppSettings.Pwd}\ntest: {this.test}");
            _realm.Write( () => _realm.Add(this.AppSettings, update: true) );



        }

        private AppSettings GetSettings()
        {

            var cfg = _realm.All<AppSettings>().SingleOrDefault();

            if (cfg == null)
            {
                cfg = new AppSettings();
                _realm.Write(() => _realm.Add(cfg));
            }
         

            return cfg;
        }
```

And my Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="WeixlerZeitenschreiber.Views.SettingPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WeixlerZeitenschreiber.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:SettingsViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        
        <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
            <Setter Property="Spacing" Value="8"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"></Setter>
        </Style>
        
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Ändern" Command="{Binding ChangeConfig}"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>


    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout  >


                <Label Text="Personal-Details" FontSize="Title" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                <Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="Bisque">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="Personalnummer" ></Label>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding AppSettings.PersonId}" Placeholder="1000001"></Entry>
                        <Label Text="Name"/>
                        <Entry Placeholder="Muster Mann" Text="{Binding test}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>


                <BoxView HeightRequest="20"></BoxView>

                <Label Text="Smtp-Einstellungen" FontSize="Title"/>
                <Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="Bisque">
                    <StackLayout >
                        <Label Text="Host:"/>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding Config.Host}" Placeholder="mail.gmx.net"/>
                        <Label Text="Port"/>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding Config.Port}" Placeholder="587"/>
                        <Label Text="E-Mail:"></Label>
                        <Entry x:Name="MailAdress" Text="{Binding AppSettings.MailAdress}" Placeholder="abc@gmx.net"></Entry>
                        <Label Text="Mail Passwort"></Label>
                        <Entry x:Name="MailPwd" Text="{Binding AppSettings.Pwd}" IsPassword="True" Placeholder="****" ></Entry>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>


            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
    

</ContentPage>
```

I can't figure out why this isn't working. Anyone had similar problems?

Comment: `{Binding Config.Host}` - your VM does not have a property named `Config`.

Comment: Right, i changed the property name but the upper Binding doesn't work neither

Comment: what did you change it to?

Comment: if you changed to `AppSettings`, that is not a C# property.  You can only bind to **public properties**

Comment: I has to be a **public property**.  Read the C# docs if you are not sure what that means